# jquery issue with mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am posting this issue in response to a question I asked a few days ago, I have created a fiddle to hopefully give a more clear explanation. I can hover over a div (with a css hover attribute), have another div pop up on another part of the screen while in mouseover state. have it disappear when i mouseleave. when I click the hover div, the red div that was disappearing and reappearing, stays, and another div pops up (as a popup state). I can click the new blue box to close both blue div, and red div. after the first iteration, I hover over original hover div, and the red div pops up again. only this time, when I mouse leave, the red div remains (does not disappear like it originally did... any tips or tricks would be most helpful.

```
$('#bg').on({
    mouseover: function () {
        $('#bg2').css('display', 'block');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('#bg2').css('display', 'none');
    },
    click: function () {
        $('#bg3').css('display', 'block'),
        $('#bg').off('mouseleave');
    }
});

$('#bg3').on({
    click: function () {
        $('#bg3').css('display', 'none'),
        $('#bg2').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skinnyb/0vvk945y/1/

Comment: which browsers have you tested this on ? Just in the spirit of tracking down the problem

Comment: chrome and safari. am scared to even attempt in IE...

Comment: Your main issue is that .off() removes the ".mouseleave()" event, permanently and you never add the event again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vvk945y/2/)***

```
function mouseLeaveStuff() { // Create a function
    $('#bg2').hide();
}

$('#bg').on({
    mouseenter: function () { // (P.S: Use mouseenter with mouseleave)
        $('#bg2').show();
    },
    mouseleave: mouseLeaveStuff, // Use your function
    click: function () {
        $('#bg3').show(),
        $('#bg').off('mouseleave'); // Off event
    }
});

$('#bg3').on({
    click: function() {
        $('#bg3, #bg2').hide();
        $('#bg').on('mouseleave', mouseLeaveStuff); // Reassign event and function
    }
});
```

---

if you prefer you can also rewrite all your code into:

```
var activated = 0;

$("#bg").hover(function(){
    if(!activated) $('#bg2').toggle();
}).click(function(){
    activated = 1;
    $("#bg3").show().on("click", function(){
        activated = 0;
        $( "#bg2" ).add( this ).hide();
    });
});
```

**EDIT: as per-request**

if you want to use multiple elements, you'd better got using `.` class instead of `#` ID:

```js
$(".bg").each(function(){
  var $bg  = $(this);
  var $bg2 = $bg.nextAll('.bg2:first');
  var $bgP = $bg.nextAll('.bgpopup:first');
  $bg.data("activated", 0).hover(function(){
    if($bg.data("activated") === 0) $bg2.toggle();
  }).click(function(){
    $bg.data("activated", 1);
    $bgP.show().on("click", function(){
      $bg.data("activated", 0);
      $bg2.add( this ).hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.bg {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
}
.bg:hover {
  background: #000;
}
.bg2 {
  position:absolute; top:250px;
  left:250px;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  display:none;
}
.bgpopup {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bg">1</div>
<div class="bg2">1</div>
<div class="bgpopup">1</div>

<div class="bg">2</div>
<div class="bg2">2</div>
<div class="bgpopup">2</div>
```

Comment: Roko, I am using your solution. if I wanted to add another initial element on the page (same as #bg, with a different name selector), how would I do so? the reason I ask is, I used the function you provided twice in the same document. If I close the current active state. everything functions correctly. if I click to open the other function before closing the other active state, I lose my mouseleave functionally (while off of both elements).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skinnyb/0vvk945y/3/
once one is clicked, you can close, and the functionality works as expected. if it is not closed, and the other is clicked, when you hover the original that was clicked, than mouse off, the hover state remains... please let me know if this needs clarification. thanks!

Comment: in the end, I wish to have 16 original hover/clickable elements, but that is far over my head... I think if I can get this as far as click this element, turn off these elements, and still keep the correct functionality as far as hover for the none active states, I can figure out some longwinded code...

Comment: @MitchBarlow you should follow the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) directives... Copy-pasting code is a mess. Use Classes instead of ID.

Comment: in addition, I think I missed this in my code when I provided my second snippet, if one element is already activated, when i click the other element, how would that close the initial (already activated state)?

Comment: @MitchBarlow If you found already an answer to your question, I kindly suggest you to ask a new one.

Comment: sorry man, not great with code, and not real familiar with stackoverflow. I appreciate your help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> does not disappear like it originally did

That's because `off` method in your `click` handler removes the bound `mouseleave` handler. You should either rebind the `mouseleave` handler to the element or use a flag.

Answer (score 1):

add the `mouseleave` again

```
$('#bg3').on({
    click: function () {
        $('#bg3').css('display', 'none'),
        $('#bg2').css('display', 'none');

        $('#bg').on({mouseleave: function () {
            $('#bg2').css('display', 'none');
        }}); 
    }
});
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cL9tjt4q/)

Comment: thanks Dy, this solution as well as Roko's were spot on.